# Can you call Moose::before in an imported function with local context

Tags: perl, moose

I'm writing a client for a REST server using Moose and trying to map the calls into objects.  Since many of the calls are simple and will use a boilerplate function to pre-fetch it, I'm trying to use export a function that creates the actual `before` functions within each class.

```
package R::A;

use Moose;

use R::Util qw(make_befores);

has 'var' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str');

make_befores('/servercall/' => ['var']);

1;

package R::Util;

use Moose; use Moose::Exporter;

sub make_befores {
    while (my ($c, $vs) = each(@_)){
        before $vs => sub {
            # make call and set object values
        };
    }
}

Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    as_is     => [ 'make_befores', ],
);

1;
```

That's probably incomplete and definitely untested but I think it relays the point.  When calling `make_befores`, it calls it in context of `R::Util` and breaks since it doesn't call it as `R::A` with all its variables and such.  If `make_befores` is simply copy-and-pasted into `R::A`, it works.  This will be used in multiple classes, though, so I want it to be an import-able function.

Or am I going about this all wrong?

UPDATED:

Fuji Goro's solution worked great, but was hard to figure out for a Moose newbie like myself, so here's what it ended up looking like:

```
sub make_befores {
    my $meta = shift;
    while (my ($c, $vs) = each(@_)){
        my $sub = sub { ... };
        Moose::Util::add_method_modifier($meta, before => [$vs => $sub]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before` is just a syntactic sugar to the MOP. See `Moose.pm`. Use MOP directly, or you can use `Moose::Util::add_method_modifier()` and `with_meta` for this case.

```
use Moose::Util;
use Moose::Exporter;

sub make_before {
    my($meta, @methods) = @_;
    Moose::Util::add_method_modifier($meta, before => \@methods);
}

Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    with_meta => [qw(make_before)],
);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Took me forever to figure out how to use that stuff, though.  I appended the solution to my question in case someone stumbles upon this.

Comment: The magic is `with_meta`, which adds a meta object (`__PACKAGE__->meta`) as the first argument of the function to export. Almost all the Moose sugar functions are exported `with_meta`. Read Moose.pm, it's really simple.